# Recommendation for creating DAL objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-access-layer, business-objects, csla

Can you recommend a DAL object creator that is simple yet useful. I want something that creates and updates object the way LINQ does. It should be in c# and much better if it splits object's properties and data access methods in partial classes.

We've used CSLA before but I want something more simplier for our next project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an ORM, see here:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)

Are you just looking to use raw ADO.NET and also maybe datasets?  If so, do you want a code generator to generate your data layer for you without a full blown ORM?

If you want to use Linq (not Linq-To-Sql), then you need an ORM at this point.

CSLA is not really an ORM and doesn't really do much from a data layer perspective.  It is more of a business layer tool.

Answer (score 3):

Just a humble recommendation as there are plenty of great products out there - we have been using EntitySpaces (an ORM) for a couple of years at our shop and like it.

Comment: @thedugas - It looks good I will take a look at it. Have you used something free?

Comment: I am currently investigating using entityspaces and would love it if you expanded on what you liked about it in particular.

Comment: @Jojo - no, I haven't, but you might find this post of interest:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5

Comment: @Russell - a couple of things I like in particular:
1. Hierarchical Data Model
2. Dynamic Query API