# What is a good lightweight ORM for our needs?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, orm

Ok I know "what X should I use" is very broad so let me narrow down our usage scenario. Basically, we should have been using an ORM a long time ago. Now though there is no way we can go through and rewrite every line of generated SQL Queries in our C# code. But we want to at least take a few steps in the right direction. So when we write new code(and in free time with refactoring) we want to convert over to some sort of ORM.

What would be a good ORM for this purpose? We are using .Net 3.5 and ASP.Net(webforms). There is nothing insanely complex about our database except for a few tables have a "dynamic" schema. We have a numerous amount of views(not used by the web application much though) and we have/use very few stored procedures. Our database is SQL Server 2005. Our price range is as cheap as possible and open source is preferred. This is a proprietary project however so we can't use a GPL library and such.

About the dynamic schema: Basically in some instances a column(of varying types) can be added or removed to certain tables.

And our view usage is almost non-existent and we could always take out the stored procedure code.. I believe there is only 2 or 3 in the database.

Comment: MyBatis.NET (former iBatis) http://www.mybatis.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/mybatisnet/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which ORM for .NET would you recommend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505/what-are-your-favorite-net-object-relational-mappers-orm, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5

Comment: @Corbin I'm looking for a more personalized opinion. I am completely new to ORMs but I know that not every ORM out there is going to fit my needs well.

Comment: @Earlz, I realize everyone has unique needs, but if we add a question for every unique project it seems that we'll have incredible duplication. The questions above contain answers that describe pros and cons and scenarios where the ORM is appropriate. I think they'll be able to help you without a brand new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql

Comment: @Corbin well also look at how old that possible duplicate is... all the posts are from 2008. Surely something has changed in 2 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would second Justin on suggesting Linq-to-SQL - it's really not dead!

If that's not your choice, or if you need to go against something like SQLite, you should definitely also check out [Subsonic 3.0](http://subsonic.github.io/) - lightweight, easy to use, free, with source - you name it.

Comment: Subsonic has a really small learning curve and I got it up and running and doing the first query in about 30 minutes in our project.. It seems like the tool for the job..

Comment: Note: I wouldn't recommend SubSonic to anyone anymore. It doesn't support joins at all. Any join will do a full table scan. However, the project [BLToolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is similar, but has working joins

Answer (score 8):

Massive - https://github.com/robconery/massive

or

PetaPoco - https://github.com/toptensoftware/petapoco

Both are single .cs files with no dependencies except what's in the GAC.

(full disclosure, PetaPoco is something I wrote)

Comment: First time that I hear about PetaPoco. Nice. Will give it a spin.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that for .NET 3.5 you could use LINQ to SQL which is free, supports Views and Stored Procedures, and has a small learning curve. The only thing I think you'd run in to trouble trying to use would be your "dynamic schema" tables (which you might want to elaborate on).

Another Open Source alternative would be [nHibernate](https://nhibernate.info) which is a great ORM, but has a much steeper learning curve in my opinion.

Comment: A steep learning curve, but the view at the top is worth the climb.

Comment: check out FluentNHibernate and/or Castle ActiveRecord to ease the steepness.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy using [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) for easy data access it generates classes using T4 so it really easy to change what is being generated. Its more of an active record style data access then a true ORM like nHibernate but linq to sql isn't a true ORM either.

Comment: SubSonic is awesome assuming you never need to do joins. For this project(at the time), we used SubSonic and then a year later after figuring out it's huge performance problem with joins, rewrote it in another T4 generating ORM (that I can't remember right now)

Comment: I would be interested in the name if you think of it I like t4 feature a lot.

Comment: Just going to update you. Finally remembered the name of the SubSonic replacement I used: [BLToolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Bit higher learning curve, but it's joins are actually joins. Not full table scans