# Retrieving data from SQL into a class

Tags: c#, sql

Let's say my SQL database contains a table called 'Customer'. This Customer has an ID, a first name, a last name and an image (`byte[]`).

What I would like is a type (class) on the client that has an `int`, two `strings` and a `byte[]`. Each record would then be read into each one of these.

I know a little of C#, but I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to accessing with C#, although I have been able to pull down records from a remote server. I'd just like to sort them once they arrive on the client side.

**Edit**: Okay, it seems I was a bit vague for people's liking, so let me clarify. I know how to make a class, and I have looked up the details about bringing data across from an SQL database into a C# project using ADO.NET commands.

What I want to know is how to mirror the information in the SQL table as an object in my C# project. So, for example, I download one record from my table, it goes into an object.

Previously I've used Silverlight and that has an EDMX model and a domain service class. If anyone is familiar with this behaviour, it's basically what I'm trying to emulate. I'd use that, but one of the limitations I face is that I'm restricted to using the application side alone, not the web site.

Thanks.

Comment: this question is too broad. What you're trying to do is DataAccess and binding that data to an object. I'm sure there's tons of information about doing so already.

Comment: You should do a google search for Linq to Sql tutorials.

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch data from database or how to create a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about creating an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object-Relational Mapper), which is a bit too broad to be answered fully in a single answer here.

There's a detailed tutorial on how to write one [here](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Creating-an-ORM-in-C-Part-1.aspx).

However, it should be noted that there are a large number of ORM tools for .NET already out there, and many of them are already listed in other questions on this site, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5).

Answer (score 7):

Here a short example on how you can retrieve your data using a data reader:

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=Your_Server;Initial Catalog=Your_Database;Integrated Security=SSPI;")) {
    cnn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        // Get ordinals from the customers table
        int custIdOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("CustomerID");
        int nameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Name");
        int imageOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Image");
        while (reader.Read()) {
            var customer = new Customer();
            customer.CustomerID = reader.GetInt32(custIdOrdinal);
            customer.Name = reader.IsDBNull(nameOrdinal)
                            ? null
                            : reader.GetString(nameOrdinal);
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(imageOrdinal)) {
                var bytes = reader.GetSqlBytes(imageOrdinal);
                customer.Image = bytes.Buffer;
            }
            customers.Add(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

If a table column is nullable then check reader.IsDBNull before retrieving the data.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) article on mapping data types for the CLR.
Here's a class definition for a customer:

```
public class Customer {
public int ID {get;private set;}
public string fName {get; set;}
public string lName {get; set;}
public byte[] image {get; set;}
}
```

You may want to look at linq to SQL to understand the sorting bit, there is an `.OrderBy(f=>f.Name);` you can apply to do an order by of your dataset.

Need a bit more information as to what you are after?

Comment: +1 for a good start.  I'm guessing he just has no idea where to start.

Comment: Break it down into smaller pieces, I could only answer based on the content of the question.  Hopefully it will get him started.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and filling a `DataTable` with the information you need.